# TODAY() in cell description for automization

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to automatize a daily routine. I am collecting different values from several Excel Worksheets everyday to use them in a different worksheet. The name of these Excel Worksheets includes today's date eg ITR 21.10.2020. My code so far is

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/('[ITR 21.10.2020.xlsx]Transactions'!I:I<>""),'[ITR 21.10.2020.xlsx]Transactions'!I:I)
```

This works but, what I want to know is: Is there a way so that I won't have to change the date in the code everyday? Is there a way to automate this? Like using `[ITR 'TODAY()'.xlsx.....]`?

Thank you!

Comment: Look into INDIRECT, but it will require that the workbook be open.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at populating the cells with a WorkBook.Open method, using code such as:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
        Dim xdate As String
        xdate = Range("A1").Value
        xdate = Format(xdate, "dd.mm.yyyy")
        Range("A1").Clear
        Range("A1").Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/('[ITR " & xdate & ".xlsx]Transactions'!I:I<>""),'[ITR " & xdate & ".xlsx]Transactions'!I:I)"
End Sub
```

This will put todays date into your cell, store it as a variable in the correct format then put your formula back into the cell.

This will only work if you put it into the 'ThisWorkbook' module.